# how to keep objects in place when window is resized in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, window

How can I keep the objects of my window (buttons, labels, etc) in center when the window is resized?

Currently, I have 3 buttons in a Windows Form. When I maximize the window, the buttons stay at the top left section of the window. I want them to be in the center as they were when the window was not maximized.

Any help?

Comment: You can disable 'Maximize' option if it's not required... :)

Answer (score 31):

You should set the Anchor properties of the object to **none**,

This will keep it in the middle.

Comment: In addition to keeping the objects in the center horizontally, if you also need the objects stay at the bottom of the screen when you expand the window vertically, set the anchor to bottom instead of none.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `Anchor` property of your controls correctly.  By default your control is anchored to `Top,Left`.  If you clear this property (anchor to nothing, essentially), your button will remain centered.

(It may seem like you want to anchor to all four sides, but in reality what this will do is resize your button to fill the form!)

Comment: I did it. Thanks. But it is not resizing the buttons. When I maximize the window, the buttons are same size as they were before. Is there any way the buttons also increase their sizes with same proportion?

Comment: If you set `Anchor` to `Top, Left, Bottom, Right` then the button will resize as you size the form, but it will not maintain the same *proportion* to the form (that is, it'll resize by the same number of pixels as the form does).  If you want to keep the button's size as a fixed percentage of the form size, you'll need to code that manually.

Answer (score 4):

To keep your layout fixed and in the middle do this:

1. On your `Form` add `TableLayoutPanel`.
2. Set it's `Dock` property to `Fill`.
3. Create 3 rows and 3 columns.
4. Edit rows and columns - set 50% for first and last column and row.
5. Set fixed size for middle row and column.
6. Place `Panel` or anything else you like in 2nd row and 2nd column. It will always be in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the visual designer of Visual Studio (And you have no reason not to), the property of your control you seek to manage how they are placed inside a form is "Anchor".
By default, when you create a new control, it is set to "Top-Left", which mean they would stay in a fixed position to the top left of your form. You can change that to anchor them to anything.

You can also disable the anchors and control their position by overriding the Resize method of the form.